# Запятая перед союзами "и" и "или"

Tags: запятые, и, или

Укажите, пожалуйста, где в этом предложении нужны знаки препинания, и почему?

**Ты видишь в этом проблему(,) и так людям делать не надо(,) или это разрешено, если возникает необходимость?**

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147973/discussion-on-question-by-misha20062006------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Будем честными: в правилах такого нет. А дополнять их никто не собирается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ не по справочникам для корректоров, а **по смыслу** (как я его **поняла**).

**Примечание.** В справочниках сложно найти готовое решение для этого предложения. Не исключено, что такой решенный вариант где-то есть, но всегда полезно найти решение самостоятельно. Именно так можно проверить свои знания в правописании.

Я бы написала так (отвечаю автору по его уточнению смысла в комментариях):

***Ты видишь в этом проблему и так людям делать не надо, или это разрешено, если возникает необходимость?***

**Пояснение**

Я делю предложение на две части (два блока). Первый блок – это ССП, а второй – СПП.

**Перед союзом ИЛИ** ставим запятую, **обозначая это деление** на блоки. **А перед союзом И** запятой нет, так как два предложения в составе ССП объединены общим смыслом (это содержание первого блока).

Обе части в составе сложного предложения **вопросительные**, но мы относим вопрос к каждому блоку **в отдельности**.

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

**[ПАС по ред. Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136)**

§ 132. В сложных синтаксических конструкциях, распадающихся на крупные логико-синтаксические блоки, которые сами по себе являются сложными предложениями или в которых один из блоков оказывается сложным предложением, **на стыке блоков** ставятся знаки препинания, указывающие на взаимоотношения блоков, при сохранении внутренних знаков, поставленных на своем собственном синтаксическом основании.

**Пояснение**

Вопросительная интонация объединяет два простых предложения в составе ССП, но она не может **объединить блоки**. Отношение между блоками выражает **разделительный союз ИЛИ,** перед ним ставится **запятая**. Блоки нужно обязательно как-то **разделить.** Запятой для этого достаточно, более сильного знака не нужно.

Внутри первого блока **запятую не ставим,** так как два простых предложения в составе СПП нужно объединить **в один блок** по смыслу, а запятая не позволит это сделать.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147986/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.